# $ 0=1 $ ? Where is the mistake?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I just found this formula although it can be easily derived.

Let $ n $ be any integer then,

$$n=\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+.....}}$$

So if I plug in $ 0 $ in this equation I get,

$$0=\sqrt{0-0+\sqrt{0-0+....}}$$

> $$0=\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+....}}}$$—————->1

But if I plug in $1$ in the equation I get,

$$1=\sqrt{1^{2}-1+\sqrt{1^{2}-1+.....}}$$

> $$1=\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+....}}}$$,—————->2

Which gives me that 0=1.Where is the mistake?

Edit:
Equation 1 can also be derived by the following method

$$1=\sqrt{0+\sqrt{1}}$$

$$1=\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{1}}}$$

.
.
.
$$1=\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+....}}}$$

Ok so let me tell you how I derived it.

I came across this particular expression,

$$x=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+.....}}}$$ which actually gives me the golden ratio,

So I chose n to be an integer and let x be the value of the following expression,
$$x=\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+...}}}$$.

After solving for x you get it’s value to be!

$$x=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4n}}{2}$$
(I took a positive sign since x is greater than or equal to 0)
So x can be an integer whenever n=0,2,6,10,20.....

When n=2,x=2(since x>0) and we get,

$$2=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+......}}$$

Similarly for n=6,x=3,

$$3=\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+......}}$$

So x is an integer whenever $$n=k^{2}-k$$ where k is a non-negative integer.Substituting $$n=k^{2}-k$$ you get x=k.

After all this I get,

> $$n=\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+.....}}$$

Comment: "easily proved" ????

Comment: Yeah why not?(proved/derived)

Comment: The mistake is in your formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem arises because you didn't really defined the radical expression

$$\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+\cdots}}}.$$

Let us rewrite it as the recurrence

$$a_{k+1}=\sqrt{n^2-n+a_k}.$$

Then with $n=0$ or $1$,

$$a_{k+1}=\sqrt{a_k}=\sqrt[4]{a_{k-1}}=\cdots\sqrt[2^{k+1}]{a_0}.$$

For $a_0=0$, we have the limit $a_\infty=0$, and for $a_0>0$, $a_\infty=1$, so you could indeed assign the expression the value $0$ or $1$, and the equation

$$n=\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+\cdots}}}$$ may hold or not depending on the value of $a_0$.

---

In other words, the truth is that you should write
$$0=\sqrt{0^{2}-0+\sqrt{0^{2}-0+\sqrt{0^{2}-0+\cdots0}}}$$
$$1=\sqrt{1^{2}-1+\sqrt{1^{2}-1+\sqrt{1^{2}-1+\cdots1}}}$$

while you innocently assumed

$$1=\sqrt{1^{2}-1+\sqrt{1^{2}-1+\sqrt{1^{2}-1+\cdots\color{red}0}}}.$$

---

For other $n$, if there is convergence, we have

$$a(a-1)=n(n-1)$$ and

$$a=\frac{1\pm|1-2n|}2.$$

For $n>1$, the only positive possibility is $a=n$. Otherwise, there could be two solutions, presumably depending on the initial value. But you can't spare convergence analysis.

Comment: Yeah I think I messed up with the final term since any number can be expressed in that form,$$n=\sqrt{0+n^{2}}$$ then,$$n=\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+n^{4}}}$$ which gives me the same thing $$n=\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+........}}$$

Comment: @user631874: you messed-up by lack of rigor, not defining the radical expression, as warned by 5xum. And you continue to do so.

Answer (score 5):

You claim the equation $$n=\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+.....}}$$ can be easily proved/derived. Can you provide the proof/derivation?

The proof/derivation should consist of two parts:

1. A strict definition of what $\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+.....}}$ means
2. A strict proof that, using the definition of $\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+.....}}$, it is equal to $n$.

Comment: I’m sorry I meant it can be derived by using induction

Comment: @user631874 OK, I would love to see the derivation. Can you provide it?

Comment: It might be worth adding that the fact that $0=1$ can be derived from the formula $n = \sqrt{n^2-n + \sqrt{n^2-n + \cdots}}$ is itself a proof that the formula, whatever it means, is false.

Comment: It only has approximate value, choose $n=2$.

Comment: I would post the derivation soon but you can test the equation by plugging in other integers

Comment: @user631874 I cannot test the equation because you haven't yet provided a definition of $\sqrt{n^2-n + \sqrt{n^2-n+\cdots}}$.

Comment: I'm going to guess your 'proof' is going to be something like: assume true, then $0=0$ ,which isn't a proof

Comment: @user631874 Also, *you* just tested the equation, you plugged in $1$ and discovered that it does not hold!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming convergence:

$$a=\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+.....}}$$

$$a=\sqrt{n^2-n+a}$$

$$a^2=n^2-n+a$$

$$a^2-a=n^2-n$$

$$a(a-1)=n(n-1)$$

For the case $n=1$:

$$a(a-1)=0$$

Notice that $a$ has roots $1$ and $0$. Why did you assume $a$ to be one of them, $1$? All $a$ that satisfies $a=\sqrt{n^2-n+a}$ and is positive is correct.

Comment: I’m not assuming but I’m asking why can’t it be 1

Comment: @user631874 You are assuming that $a=1$ when you assume that $\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+\cdots}}=n$.

Comment: Similarly, for n=0, can't a be either of 0 or 1?

Comment: Is this another case where on squaring both sides extra solutions get produced?

Comment: First quesiton: yes. Second question: no, this has two solutions. Consider $a=sqrt(3+a)$, it has one solution as we know that it's nonnegative although $a^2=3+a$ has two solutions. Because both are nonnegative in this answer, it has two roots.

Comment: When a=1 it is positive and also satisfies $$a=\sqrt{n^{2}-n+a}$$ for n=1

Answer (score 0):

As most have been doing, assuming convergence, let,
$$k=\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+\cdots}}$$
Squaring both sides,
$$k^2=n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+\cdots}$$ 
$$k^2=n^2-n+k$$
$$k^2-k-(n^2-n) = 0$$
$$k=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{4n^2-4n+1}}{2}$$
$$k=\frac{1\pm(2n-1)}{2}$$
$$k={n,1-n}$$
Now, we have to be careful. Squaring produced extra solutions. So, we must verify which ones are right for what domains.

Clearly, $\forall n<0, 1-n$ is the candidate and $\forall n>1, n$ is the answer.

For $n=0, k$ is trivially 0.

Finally, for $n=1, k=1-n$ as you have verified.

In a summary,

$$k=$$ \begin{cases} 
      1-n & n< 0,n=1 \\
      n & 1< n,n=0\\
   \end{cases}

P.S. I'm not sure if this is correct. I would be glad if someone could verify this.